How to fix error downloading CocoaPods from my Unity project?
I am programming a mobile game using unity, when trying to build and run I get
"Error building Player: iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in a non-functional Xcode project."
And then the Xcode project can't manage sign-ins.enter image description here
I tried deleting and installing CocoaPods because I saw CocoaPods was install when running the External Dependency Manager. Unity recognized my deletion and installation but they didn't change the situation.

Please post the actual error rather than a screenshot.

If you are able to make unity build then you can go to build folder and open the terminal and just run the command "Pod install" this will auto install the all dependency and a new .workspace file will generate in the same folder.
But If you can share the exact screenshot this will provide us more detail.

https://imgur.com/a/kAycdrO This is a screenshot of me trying to use pod install. and the screen I sent is the exact same error written inside of unity console
